# "Remove a rib [from Adam] to make a whole other person"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to stand in for the concept of *"Remove a rib [from Adam] to make a whole other person"*

The sentence I am trying to write is: This will effectively end her ability to ____.

I am trying to use it as a metaphor to describe the way the matrilineal family reproduces itself in the neo-slave narrative *Corregidora* by Gayl Jones.

Comment: Single word requests require to be properly presented in order to be accepted. Please take (or re-visit) the Tour to ensure your question is within guidelines.

Comment: I just took the tour! I must have missed this. Someone submitted edits for my question that I approved. Is there something else wrong with it? Kindly point it out and I will gladly fix it.

Comment: You need to supply a sentence in to which the word will fit. One of the reasons for this is so that users may clearly see what part of speech you are requiring.

Comment: The original document states _And the rib, which the LORD God had taken from man, made he a woman, and brought her unto the man_. [KJV Genesis 2:22]. So the word you seek would be "making".

Comment: Still makes no sense.  About all I can figure is "play God", since only God can remove a rib from Adam to create Eve.

Comment: *'to regenerate'* is currently too strongly connected with repair (lizard tails etc) but *'to procreate;'* would that be weighty enough, and not too abstruse?

Comment: The later scriptures make it clear that Adam was a 'figure' of Christ [Romans 5:14] and the taking of a rib pre-figures the lance piercing Jesus after his death by crucifixion. Thus the creation of Eve is a figure of the Church being 'born' out of Christ. So a word to describe the Genesis account might be 'a demonstration'. That is, a demonstration of what would be in the future.

Comment: @NigelJ the OP didn't ask for a biblical term, and the context definitely seems secular. Not everyone believes in the scriptures. Your comments seem to border on proselytising.

Comment: Canyou give more context for that sentence? Presumably you're using the Biblical verse as a metaphor of something, but it is not clear at all what. What is the situation which would end up having a sentence which implies of a person that she had the rib-person-creation ability once but then lost it?

Comment: Clarification for Mitch: You're right, I am trying to use it as a metaphor to describe the way the matrilineal family reproduces itself in the neo-slave narrative _Corregidora_ by Gayl Jones. Clarification for Nigel and Chappo: I am fine with a biblical term if one is available. I appreciated the grounding of the 'demonstration' suggestion in the text that my question emerges from. I do not find it proselytizing to receive the context/interpretation/arc provided. Found it very engaging.

Comment: The question is insufficiently clear. To make another person in a way that's like ("a metaphor for") the creation story in what sense(s)? For now, I vote to close as unclear.

Comment: @Chappo The context was altered five hours after my comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, from the limited context you've provided, that you have a female character who has the ability to reproduce herself by taking a portion of her body (e.g. a rib) which then grows into a new person. If I've misunderstood, please correct me.

In that case, the single word most suitable would be:

**[replicate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/replicate)**

> 1 Make an exact copy of; reproduce.
>
> 1.1 **(replicate itself)** (of genetic material or a living organism) reproduce or give rise to a copy of itself.
>
> - ‘interleukin-16 prevents the virus from replicating itself’
> - *[no object]* ‘in order to replicate, cells must make copies of their
>   DNA’

Or if you could accept two words, the more accurate term would be "clone herself":

**[clone](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clone)**

> 1 Propagate (an organism or cell) as a clone.

[the same source defines the noun form as "An organism or cell, or group of organisms or cells, produced asexually from one ancestor or stock, to which they are genetically identical."]